# Is there any way to get same app design in windows phone from android app?

Tags: android, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone app. I want same design and structure in all xaml pages of windows phone as they are in an android app. Is there any easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a special msdn pages for you - [Android to Windows Phone API Mapping Tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223497), [Windows Phone 7 for Android Application Developers](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223498) and [Leveraging your Android development Expertise to Build Windows Phone Applications Blog Post](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223500).

Direct porting is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a cross platform development suite or sdk. There are some out there that target the major platforms like iOS, Android, and Windows Phone 8. Some include Appcelerator, Marmalade, and Xamarin. But most of them cost money. Check this link for more.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2012/12/03/what-cross-platform-development-tools-support-windows-8-and-windows-phone.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all i have to mention that it is against design guidelines, but you can do as you wish.

Now you have to decide: Hybrid app or native?

If hybryd:

XAMARIN - C# logic and native UI - you have to know something from each platform
PhoneGap - HTML + CSS but you will find many other problems

If native:

Yes, you can do it XAML allows you to build you'r control as complicated as you'r imagination alows you to...

I had an experience in developing native C#+XAML application on windows phone, that should be at least 90% the same design - and all went good.

And the easies way will be to use style resources for your app, you will create/modify control once, and then just add style to same controls, in example:

You want same button color, form, focus state, pressed state as Android.
1) Just modify the default button template
2) Make this style as a global resource
3) Apply to every button you want